# Find asymptotically equivalent function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, asymptotics

I'm trying to understand the steps of this example (finding an asymptotically equivalent function).
But the last two stay a little foggy for me.

$(n+1)\ln (n+1)-n\ln n$

$=(n+1)\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)+\ln n$

$=(n+1)\left(\frac{1}{n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)+\ln n$

$=1+\frac{1}{n}+o(1)+\ln n$

$=\ln n+o(\ln n)$

Hence $(n+1)\ln (n+1)-n\ln n \sim \ln n$

Why can we get rid of the $\frac{1}{n} + o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ ?

And how comes the $o(\ln n)$ ?

More details and explanations would be welcome !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your difficulty, here are more intermediate steps:
$$(n+1)\biggl(\frac{1}{n}+o\Bigl(\frac{1}{n}\Bigr)\biggr)=\frac{n+1}n+o\Bigl(\frac{n+1}{n}\Bigr)=1+\frac 1n+o(1)$$
since $\frac{n+1}n\sim_\infty 1$ and hence $\:o\bigl(\frac{n+1}{n}\bigr)=o(1)$.

Last step: the constant $1$ is $o(\ln n)$, hence $o(1)$ is too, $\frac1n=o(\ln n)$, so their sum is also $o(\ln n)$.

Answer (score 0):

As a check,
since
$(x\ln(x))'
=\ln(x)+1
$,
by the mean value theorem,
$(n+1)\ln(n+1)-n\ln(n)
=\ln(n+c)+1
$
where $0 \le c \le 1$.

Then
$\ln(n+c)-\ln(n)
=\ln(1+c/n)$.
Since
$0 \le \ln(1+x)
\le x$
for $x \ge 0$,
$\ln(1+c/n)
=ac/n
$
where
$0 \le a \le 1$,
so
$(n+1)\ln(n+1)-n\ln(n)
=\ln(n+c)+1
=\ln(n)+1+b/n
$
where
$0 \le b \le 1$.